# Return an empty array as object with JsonModel

Tags: php, json, zend-framework2

I am making a REST method with Zend Framework 2 which returns JSON response. For that I'm using the following code:

```
return new JsonModel($result);
```

In some cases, result is an empty array and JsonModel outputs that as `[]`. Is it possible to force JsonModel to display empty array as an object, i.e. `{}`?

In PHP, you can do the following:

```
echo json_encode(array(), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Is there a similar option to `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` that I could use with JsonModel in zf2? I have tried all combinations of the following, but with no luck.

```
return new JsonModel(array(), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you'd've followed the code, you would've found that it's *not* possible with the provided `JsonModel` by Zend.

---

`Zend\View\Model\JsonModel` has this serialize function:

```
public function serialize()
{
    $variables = $this->getVariables();
    if ($variables instanceof Traversable) {
        $variables = ArrayUtils::iteratorToArray($variables);
    }

    $options = [
        'prettyPrint' => $this->getOption('prettyPrint'),
    ];

    if (null !== $this->jsonpCallback) {
        return $this->jsonpCallback.'('.Json::encode($variables, false, $options).');';
    }
    return Json::encode($variables, false, $options);
}
```

The `Json::encode` leads to `Zend\Json\Json`, and the `encode()` function

```
public static function encode($valueToEncode, $cycleCheck = false, array $options = [])
{
    if (is_object($valueToEncode)) {
        if (method_exists($valueToEncode, 'toJson')) {
            return $valueToEncode->toJson();
        }

        if (method_exists($valueToEncode, 'toArray')) {
            return static::encode($valueToEncode->toArray(), $cycleCheck, $options);
        }
    }

    // Pre-process and replace javascript expressions with placeholders
    $javascriptExpressions = new SplQueue();
    if (isset($options['enableJsonExprFinder'])
       && $options['enableJsonExprFinder'] == true
    ) {
        $valueToEncode = static::recursiveJsonExprFinder($valueToEncode, $javascriptExpressions);
    }

    // Encoding
    $prettyPrint = (isset($options['prettyPrint']) && ($options['prettyPrint'] === true));
    $encodedResult = self::encodeValue($valueToEncode, $cycleCheck, $options, $prettyPrint);

    // Post-process to revert back any Zend\Json\Expr instances.
    $encodedResult = self::injectJavascriptExpressions($encodedResult, $javascriptExpressions);

    return $encodedResult;
}
```

As you can see, the encoding function has been commented for you, so we need the `self::encodeValue` function, clicking through on that leads to:

```
private static function encodeValue($valueToEncode, $cycleCheck, array $options, $prettyPrint)
{
    if (function_exists('json_encode') && static::$useBuiltinEncoderDecoder !== true) {
        return self::encodeViaPhpBuiltIn($valueToEncode, $prettyPrint);
    }

    return self::encodeViaEncoder($valueToEncode, $cycleCheck, $options, $prettyPrint);
}
```

Judging by your question, you have `json_encode` built-in function available, so we step *into* the `if()` and execute the `self::encodeViaPhpBuiltIn()` function:

```
private static function encodeViaPhpBuiltIn($valueToEncode, $prettyPrint = false)
{
    if (! function_exists('json_encode') || static::$useBuiltinEncoderDecoder === true) {
        return false;
    }

    $encodeOptions = JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP;

    if ($prettyPrint) {
        $encodeOptions |= JSON_PRETTY_PRINT;
    }

    return json_encode($valueToEncode, $encodeOptions);
}
```

This has the same check again, but finally ends up with:

```
return json_encode($valueToEncode, $encodeOptions);
```

The options are set hardcoded in the function, with the exception of the optional "`JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`" option.

---

The answer you're looking for is: **no**, it's not possible.

---

*However*, you *could*, technically, write your own replacement for `JsonModel`, make sure that your own model is used by the `JsonViewStrategy` and use it then... Just an option.

Answer (score 0):

Use the response object:

```
    $result   = array();
    $data     = json_encode($result, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    return $response->setContent($data);
```